# How to cast a void* to access a static data member of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, casting

```
// a.h
typedef void (*DispatchFn)(void);

struct cmd {
    static const DispatchFn DISPATCH_FUNCTION;
    int ID;
};


// a.cpp
void Foo()
{
}

const DispatchFn cmd::DISPATCH_FUNCTION = &Foo;

cmd *CmdObject = (cmd *)(BufferOfMemory);
CmdObject->ID = 6969;

void *PtrToCmdObj = (void *)CmdObject;

void Process()
{
    DispatchFn Fn1 = ((cmd *)(PtrToCmdObj))->DISPATCH_FUNCTION; // <-- This points to DISPATCH_FUNCTION
    Fn1(); 

    DispatchFn Fn2 = (DispatchFn)(PtrToCmdObj); // <-- This doesn't points to DISPATCH_FUNCTION, but points to ID
    Fn2();
}
```

I know `Fn2` doesn't point to `DISPATCH_FUNCTION` because it is `static` data member. I have many different types of `cmd` so I can't cast the `PtrToCmdObj` to a specific type to access `DISPATCH_FUNCTION`.

Is there any way I can cast the `void*` to `DispatchFn` type and call the `DISPATCH_FUNCTION` without knowing the type of `cmd` beforehand

Comment: No, there is not. [Now that we got the Y out of the way, what is your X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: In the first case the pointer itself is irrelevant, only its type matters. Basically it is the same as writing `cmd::DISPATCH_FUNCTION`. Without knowing the type of `cmd` in advance there is no way to locate its static member functions. C++ does not have (built in) reflection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to do something generic I prefer to use templates.

```
  // a.h
  typedef void(*DispatchFn)(void);
  /* your template extension for static method dispatching */
  template <class T>
  struct callable
  {
    void operator()() 
    { 
      T::DISPATCH_FUNCTION(); 
      // or if u have non static class member then use this line
      // static_cast<T*>(this)->NONSTATIC_DISPATCH_FUNCTION();
    }
  };

  struct cmd : public callable<cmd> {
    static const DispatchFn DISPATCH_FUNCTION;
    int ID;
  };

  // a.cpp
  void Foo()
  {
    printf("%s", __FUNCTION__);
  }

  const DispatchFn cmd::DISPATCH_FUNCTION = &Foo;

  template <class T>
  void Process(T *PtrToCmdObj)
  {
    (*PtrToCmdObj)(); // <-- This will call DISPATCH_FUNCTION 
  }

  void run() {
    cmd *CmdObject = (cmd *)(BufferOfMemory);
    CmdObject->ID = 6969;

    Process(CmdObject);
  }
```

by making Process method template, you should call with any type of variable which provides operator() overload.